Exploring the relationship between Tensorial Techniques and Coordinate-Independence?
I am studying Differential Geometry and Riemannian Geometry.I need some help from my stack exchange community members in this regard.
Recently I happened to get a lecture series on Riemannian Geometry which is created by KAUST(King Arabia University)Visualization Community.The videos can be found in their official website.
It has a fairly good and visual representation of the content.But yet I am bothered with one thing in that lecture which I have not been able to figure out yet.
It is clear that any object having a geometric or physical interpretation has to be invariant under change of coordinates.So,when we try to define some concept which we want to be coordinate independent,we use the Tensorial Methods/Techniques;as they say in their lecture.
I am a bit confused with what tensors have to do with coordinate independence,that tensors are used to define coordinate-free concepts.There is a missing link between the two terms 'Tensor Calculus' and 'Coordinate-Independence'.
Is there anyone who could come up with an answer to my question,and correlating the above two ideas?

The word 'tensor' is used in different, say, flavors, depending on your perspective. In linear algebra, a tensor is an element of a certain vector space with a universal property (which allows you to represent multilinear maps from a product of vector spaces to some space maps through linear maps from the tensor product to that same space).
In differential geometry people often talk (rather sloppily) about tensors while they are actually talking about tensor fields. A tensor field, in classical differential geometry, is an entity which has, in a given coordinate system $x:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, a representation with a certain number of (upper and lower) indices, which transform correctly under coordinate changes, namely according to the rule
$$ t^{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_k}_{\beta_1, \beta_2, \ldots , \beta_l} = 
\frac{\partial \tilde x^{s_1}}{\partial x^{\beta_1}} \dots
\frac{\partial \tilde x^{s_1}}{\partial x^{\beta_l}} 
\frac{\partial x^{\alpha_1}}{\partial \tilde x^{r_1}}\dots 
\frac{\partial x^{\alpha_k}}{\partial \tilde x^{r_k}}
\tilde{t}^{r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_k}_{s_1, s_2, \ldots , s_1}$$
where the terms with partial derivatives represent the components of the Jacobian of the coordinate change (see [1], page 169) and the summation convention is used. This is the link between "Tensor Calculus" and "Coordinate Independence"
It turns out that this definition is equivalent to the modern approach where a tensor field is a section in a bundle over the manifold where each fiber is isomorphic to the corresponding tensor product
$$\bigotimes_k T_p M \otimes \bigotimes_l (T_pM)^* $$
If you want to see an in-depth discussion of this then you may want to read through chapter 4 of [1].
(Please don't complain if you think I did not get the indices right).
[1] Mike Spivak, A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry, Volume One, 2nd edition, Publish or Perish, Houston 1979

Rest Assured,I won't complaint about indices,Haha!Well your answer was an enriching discussion on the topic raised by me in the question and it clears all my doubts and queries.Thank you very much for helping!

Just one thing to ask,about the reference [1]Mike Spivak,Differential Geometry Volume 1 book,could you tell me where to look for a PDF or DjVu of this book?

@KishalaySarkar Sorry, no. When posting here I always assume (probably incorrectly) that people have access to a math library.
